# Entity Framework and relationships with 1: 0..n relationships, what to do when it is 0?

Tags: c#, null, navigation, associations, entity-framework-4.1

In the application I support, there are times that associations can be null as the client has not submitted the data yet. I don't know of any other way to handle this other than doing a null check. The database is set in stone (other applications consume it also) It turns my code into an mess. I was wondering if there is a better way to go about doing this (this code is going into an anonymous type, but using a class makes no difference. I can't add a predicate checking for null, because if the bill exists that information needs to be returned regardless of if claim patient or claim do not exist yet. Here is a simplified version:

```
            var baseQuery = Context.Bills.AsNoTracking()
            .Select
            (
                bill => new
                {
                    bill.BillId,
                    bill.BillStatus,
                    patientId = bill.ClaimPatient != null ? bill.ClaimPatientId : null,
                    claimPatientId =  bill.ClaimPatient != null && bill.ClaimPatient.Claim != null ? bill.ClaimPatientId : null,
                    bill.UserNumber,
                }
            );
```

And this null checking can go on and on. I know there is probably a better way, and when I see it I will face plant because it will probably be something so simple and obvious that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

I've found extensions methods like the following are sometimes useful for dealing with this.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static U Maybe<T, U>(this T t, Func<U> f) where U : class
    {
        return t != null ? f() : null;
    }

    public static U Maybe<T, U>(this T t, Func<T, U> f) where U : class
    {
        return t != null ? f(t) : null;
    }

    public static U? MaybeNullable<T, U>(this T t, Func<U> f) where U : struct
    {
        return t != null ? f() : (U?)null;
    }

    public static U? MaybeNullable<T, U>(this T t, Func<T, U> f) where U : struct
    {
        return t != null ? f(t) : (U?)null;
    }
}
```

Some example usage follows.

```
bill.ClaimPatient.Maybe(() => bill.ClaimPatientId)
bill.ClaimPatient.Maybe(cp => cp.Id)

person.Maybe(p => p.Employer).Maybe(e => e.Address)
```

Comment: That sure is a lot cleaner. i really like it. I'll keep the question open for a few minutes to see if anybody else ha something interesting to add, but it looks like you will be getting my up-vote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Good news: SQL doesn't have this `null` reference concept. So you can reduce the checks (in this case) to a simple cast to `int?`.

```
var baseQuery = Context.Bills.AsNoTracking()
.Select
(
    bill => new
    {
        bill.BillId,
        bill.BillStatus,
        patientId = (int?)bill.ClaimPatientId,
        claimPatientId = (int?)bill.ClaimPatientId,
        ClaimPatient.UserNumber,
    }
);
```

The whole statement is translated into SQL. The first thing the CLR knows is the result set coming from the database. This set may contain null values, so you only have to make sure that the final result can contains `int` and `null` in one property.

Maybe for the second Id value you need `bill.ClaimPatient.Claim != null ? bill.ClaimPatientId : null`, but I consider that business logic, rather than a null safety check.

Comment: Wow, I wonder if I even need the cast with an anonymous type in an anonymous class, although once I finish with the query I will be making a POCO for these fields. That would really clean things up in my code.

Comment: Oh yes, materializing into a named class will be just as easy.

Comment: Thanks to both Gert and Timothy.